# How consecutively play sound files in a loop in the iOS application?

Tags: ios, audio, mp3, avaudioplayer

The application for the iPhone , I want to consistently reproduce the multiple audio files (in parallel with the display images) . I put the names into an array of audio files and image files. But when I try to play in a loop image and sound after I start the application all the sounds are played simultaneously. I tried to implement separate start (with  dispatch_after), but after 12 steps in the cycle occurs at some braking.
  I think that there is any way to pause in the cycle. Until the end of the current file playback cycle does not proceed to the next step. But I do not know how it can be implemented . Can someone give advice or example code how it can be solved ?
P.S. I read about audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying, but can not figure out how to use this method in practice.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 21; i++)
  {
   double delayInSeconds = i * 4.5;
   DZpopTimeStep *tempVar = [dataPopTime objectAtIndex: i];
   tempVar.popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
   dispatch_after(tempVar.popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
           {
               //.....image
               UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageFromFile.frame.size);
               [[UIImage imageNamed:tempVar.nameColorFile] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
               UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
               UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
               UIColor *fonMain = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
               imageFromFile.backgroundColor = fonMain;

               // ... play of sound file
               [self playSoundFile:(NSString *)tempVar.nameSoundFile];
           });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out AVQueuePlayer, it seems to be what you are looking for, here is a link to it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html